# jQuery Scroll Back to Top when Reach Bottom on Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I saw this code here on Stack Overflow. It scrolls down on mouseover and scrolls to the top on mouseout:

```
var amount = '';
function scroll() {
    $('#div1').animate({
        scrollTop: amount
    }, 500, 'linear',function() {
        if (amount != '') {
            scroll();
        }
    });
}
$('#div1').hover(function() {
    amount = '+=10';
    scroll();
}, function() {
    amount = '0';
});
```

I need it to also scroll to the top when it reaches the bottom. I tried adding an if/then to the second part to scroll down only if the scroll amount is less than the div height:

```
$('#div1').hover(function() {
    if (amount < ('#div1').height()){
        amount = '=+10';
        scroll();}
    else {
        amount = '=-10';
        scroll();}
}, function() {
    amount = '0';
});
```

But that stopped all scrolling. Any assistance would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: wait, so you saw some code , and want it different, and you think there are minions working for you here ?

Comment: If you want to put it that way, fine. I've edited the post to reflect that I've tried various things but am just going in circles at this point.

Comment: this would be a lot easier if you would create a fiddle to illustrate your needs

Answer (score 0):

I think you misplaced the signs in the script for the amount number changes. It should look like this:

```
$('#div1').hover(function() {
    if (amount < ('#div1').height()){
        amount = '+=10';
        scroll();}
    else {
        amount = '-=10';
        scroll();}
}, function() {
    amount = '0';
});
```